# Close popup div if element loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following scenario: On a label's mouseover event, I display a div. The div must stay open in order to make selections within the div. On the label's mouseout event, the div must dissappear. The problem is that when my cursor moves from the label to the div, the label's mouseout event is fired, which closes the div before I can get there. I have a global boolean variable called `canClose` which I set to true or false depending on the case in which it must be closed or kept open. I have removed the functionality to close the div on the label's mouseout event for this purpose.
Below is some example code.

**EDIT**
I have found a workaround to my problem, event though Alex has also supplied a workable solution.
I added a `mouseleave` event on the label as well, with a `setTimeout` function which will execute in 1.5 seconds. This time will give the user enough time to hover over the open div, which will set `canClose` to false again.

```
$("#label").live("mouseover", function () {
        FRAMEWORK.RenderPopupCalendar();
    });

$("#label").live("mouseout", function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(canClose){
                FRAMEWORK.RemovePopupCalendar();
            }
        },1500);
    });

    this.RenderPopupCalendar = function () {
        FRAMEWORK.RenderCalendarEvents();
        }
    };


    this.RenderCalendarEvents = function () {
        $(".popupCalendar").mouseenter(function () {
            canClose = false;
        });

        $(".popupCalendar").mouseleave(function () {               
            canClose = true;
            FRAMEWORK.RemovePopupCalendar();
        });
    }

    this.RemovePopupCalendar = function () {
        if (canClose) {
            if ($(".popupCalendar").is(":visible")) {
                $(".popupCalendar").remove();
            }
        }
    };
```

Any help please?

Comment: Do the mouseleave on the popped '<div>'

Comment: Alex, I have already implemented a mouseleave on my div. That works fine. What happens is when i hover over the label, the div appears correctly, but when I move out of the label (to anywhere on the page without moving over the div), I need the div to close as well.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question .. I have a question though . Why cant you show on mouseover label and hideon mouseout div itself? ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap the `<label>` and `<div>` in a containing `<div>` then do all you mouse/hide events on that.

Check out this fiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/6MMW6/1

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will have a look at your suggestion.

Comment: Your suggestion would work in some cases, except that in my case the div container (your "dre" div) is wrapped within another div. When you hover over the label, it will stretch the "dre" container to the height of the popup div. Which will result in the parent container also stretched.

Comment: I have updated your fiddle to illustrate what is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/6MMW6/6/

Comment: position the 'dre' `div` absolutely also. Then give it a height. - http://jsfiddle.net/6MMW6/8/

Comment: This might work, I'll check it out. Thanks Alex. How do I mark a comment as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Give your popupCalendar an explicit ID instead of a class selector, e.g.

```
<div id="popupCalendar">
```

Reference it with #popupCalendar instead of .popupCalendar.

Now, remove() is quite drastic as it will completely remove the div from the DOM. If you wish to display the calendar again you should just .hide() it.

But your logic seems a bit overly complex, why not just .show() it on mouseenter and .hide() on mouseout events ?

Comment: Thanks Endy. To which element must I attach mouseenter & mouseout events? Remember, I need to show the div on the label's mouseenter, and hide the div again on mouseout (if i have not moved over the div yet). If I have moved over the div, the div needs to stay visible.

Comment: Bind the mouseenter to the label and mouseleave to the div. That way the div gets hidden when the mouse exits the div for the first time.

Comment: No luck yet Endy. The div still stays visible if I leave the label without moving over the div.

Answer (score 0):

This will close the entire tab page if the tab page loses focus.
How ever if you target it, it can work for  something within the page too, just change the target codes.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
delay=1000 // 1 sec = 1000.
closing=""
function closeme(){
closing=setTimeout("self.close()",delay)
// self means the tab page close when losing focus, but you can change and target it too.
}
<!--// add onBlur="closeme()" onfocus="clearTimeout(closing)" to the opening BODY tag//-->
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body onBlur="closeme()" onfocus="clearTimeout(closing)">
```